# How to clip data when using data driven pages in ArcMap 10?

Tags: arcmap, clip, data-driven-pages, map-book

I am working on a map book using data driven pages of the Silvies Valley in Northeastern Oregon. The basemap is a high resolution aerial image (raster) of Oregon with a shapefile overlay of USGS geologic map units. I neglected to clip the dataframe before I set up the data driven pages.

Now I would like to add contours to the map. I am using the contour tool in the raster surface toolbox,...the process has been running for about 8 hours now. I understand this is because the raster is so big.

My problem is, as far as I understand, if I turn off data driven pages in order to clip the dataframe, I will lose the data driven pages settings. This is not that big of a deal for me, but I would rather not do the work again.

My question is, how do I clip the data to the dataframe, while I have data driven pages set up?

Thanks in advance for the help, 
JL

Comment: Just for clarification, when you say clip to the data frame, do you mean an actual Clip process, or a mask? Also, are you using the USGS geologic map units shapefile to run your Data Driven Pages? Not really sure what contours have to do with your question.

Comment: I need to clip the data. ArcMap is attempting to draw contours for the entire state of Oregon (the entire raster), and I only need it to do it for the map area. The problem is that it could take days to draw the contours for the whole state.

Comment: The raster itself, the geologic unit overlay, and the index for the data-driven pages map book are the three layers driving the data driven pages. I guess I am just confused about how exactly to clip the raster to the extent of the dataframe, and not the raster.

Comment: Okay. When you run the Contour tool, set up a mask in the environment settings based on your USGS geologic map units shapefile, or whatever your area of interest is.

Comment: That worked for me, thanks. In the environment I set the processing extent to the current display.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, now that I understand the question better, I will post my answer here rather than the comments so hopefully people will find it easier.  I'll include more detail here as well.

Within the [Contour](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//009z000000ts000000.htm) tool dialog, click on the Environments button at the bottom.
[image: Contour Dialog]

In the Environment Settings, navigate to Processing Extent.  In that setting you can define the extent you want to use for processing through several different methods, including manual coordinate input.
[image]

An additional note is that this setting can be changed for many tools in ArcToolbox.